# Vectorizing multiple outer-products in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, vectorization

I have read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549082/summing-outer-product-of-multiple-vectors-in-einsum) which seems similar, but my question may be simpler.

I have a matrix **A** that is of size [N x C], and a matrix **X** that is of size [N x D]

For each *n*th row in **A**, compute it's outer product with the corresponding *n*th row in **X**. Each outer product will yield a matrix, of size [C x D]. Then, sum up all those matricies together to get the final matrix.

Is there a simple non-for-loop way to do this in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds pretty much to be `np.dot(A.T, X)`

Comment: @JulienBernu I am doing the outer-product, not the dot-product.

Comment: Yes but it is just the same here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the nth rows outer: element (c,d) is A[n,c]*X[n,d]. Now sum over all n and you get Sum_n A[n,c]*X[n,d] which is exactly (AT.X)[c,d]